# Errors in generating random multivariate binomial numbers

Tags: r

I have a real situation trying to use `bindata::rmvdata` to generate random n x 5 random multivariate binomial numbers such like that:

```
margprob<-c(0.01325, 0.31142, 0.10000, 0.02837, 0.01273) 
x<-c(0.013, 0.004, 0.002, 0.000, 
      0.000, 0.004, 0.311, 0.069, 
      0.023, 0.010, 0.002, 0.069, 
      0.100, 0.022, 0.010, 0.000, 
      0.023, 0.022, 0.028, 0.008, 
      0.000, 0.010, 0.010, 0.008, 
      0.013)

commonprob<-matrix(x, 5, 5, byrow=T)

res<-rmvbin(10000, commonprob=commonprob)

Error in commonprob2sigma(commonprob, simulvals) : 
  Extrapolation occurred ... margprob and commonprob not compatible?
```

Then I realized it's due to the pair of NAs in the sigma matrix:

```
> sigma
         [,1]    [,2]   [,3]    [,4]    [,5]
[1,]  1.00000 0.02671 0.1559 -0.5812 -0.4207
[2,]  0.02671 1.00000 0.5291  0.6024  0.6064
[3,]  0.15591 0.52908 1.0000  0.8325  0.8712
[4,] -0.58118 0.60240 0.8325  1.0000      NA
[5,] -0.42073 0.60644 0.8712      NA  1.0000
```

My question is whether there's a solution to get through of the error?

Comment: What are the NA's doing in the sigma matrix? What does that mean to you statistically?

Comment: The `rmvbin` uses the commonprob matrix to compute the sigma matrix (covariance matrix for the normal distribution) and if there're NAs, the `rmvbin` process will stop with the error above. see bindata::commonprob2sigma

Comment: Well, the problem is then where you have zeros in your commonprob matrix. in the first row, you have 0's for 4 and 5 which certainly implies a certain degree of correlation but then the correlation between isn't very large. It may be impossible to generate a correlation matrix with these probabilities.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But if I manually change the zeros to small values like 0.001, the error is still there.